# How to obtain an instance of ServiceState?

Tags: android

I'm trying to obtain an instance of `ServiceState` in my `Activity`. But how am I supposed to do this? There is no static method to obtain an instance or any method on any service that returns an `ServiceState` instance.
There is the `TelephonyManager.listen()` call. But I want to get the `ServiceState` instance when I want, not when Android calls my listener because something changed.

The documentation of `ServiceState` can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Which kind of Service do you want to observe? The network connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I did't really understand your question since as far as I can tell, ever since API level 1, there's been an empty constructor on ServiceState which is public. So if you want an instance of it, all you have to do is:

```
ServiceState serviceState = new ServiceState();
```

**Edit:**
Now that I understand your situation, the only thing I can think of is that after you register a PhoneStateListener you will get an update on the PhoneState (it may not have actually changed but an event is fired to let you know the current value I guess). So the only workaround I can think of would be to keep registering a phoneStateListener when you want to know the current value and deregistering it when you don't need it anymore.

Hope that helps

Comment: according to the documentation this is just an empty constructor. which means that it initializes an instance of a ServiceState with default values. Not current values.

Comment: After actually trying to implement it I understood your situation, I thought that if the getState() method was called on this default instance it would get the actual state, but that doesn't seem to be so..i'll edit my answer

Comment: is this just an assumption or did you actually try/verify your workaround?

Comment: I had an application where I listened to service state changes and I noticed that as soon as I registered it would give me an update (onServiceStateChanged was called). Based on that I suggested the above answer but have not tried it in those specific terms, and I don't know if this happens on every device/OS version since it doesn't directly impact my app.

Answer (score 6):

What kind of information you want to get from `ServiceState`?
If you want to get only current registered operator, you can do this by calling a method `getNetworkOperatorName()` in `TelephonyManager`.
But if you want to get service state of phone, you need to implement `PhoneStateListener` with overridden `onServiceStateChanged` method. Then make this:

```
telephonyManager.listen(yourListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
```

When you call `telephonyManager.listen`, then `onServiceStateChanged` method is called and you get current service state of phone at this time.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this yet but i'm going to have to since this sort of funcitonality is key to my app. I'll let you know how it goes, but here's the idea:

From the API (instance method of `TelephonyManager`):

> `public void listen (PhoneStateListener listener, int events)`
>
> Registers a listener object to receive notification of changes in specified telephony states.
>
> To register a listener, pass a PhoneStateListener and specify at least one telephony state of interest in the events argument. **At registration, and when a specified telephony state changes, the telephony manager invokes the appropriate callback method** on the listener object and passes the current (udpated) values.

You could just register a listener and keep it, and then get the callback to save the reported state in your Activity upon each change so that your app could just refer to the Activity field every time it needs to check. Alternatively you could keep registering and throwing out listeners every time you want a state measurement, but I think that would waste more system resources than just keeping one on.

Answer (score 2):

Some calls are not available for the developer. Period.

If you want that kind of info, you will have a `PhoneStateListener` like this [example](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/broadcastreceiver-never-calls-onreceive-t14708.html).

Comment: Yeah well, that's exactly what i described and what i don't want to do ;) i need to check ServiceState when my Activity launches for example.

Comment: You will have to think of a workaround with the `PhoneStateListener`.

Comment: I would have to change something, like activating flight mode or something like that. But i don't want to change stuff that the user don't want me to change...

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Phone State: " + serviceState.getState());
        phone_state = serviceState.getState();
        super.onServiceStateChanged(serviceState);
    }
};
```

and in OnCreate:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android 8 you have the following:

```
tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.getServiceState();
```

don't forget to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```