# How to detect phone service state

Tags: android

I read about [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) and its `onServiceStateChanged` callback. 
One of the possible service state values is STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE that I need to detect.

Can I get the phone state information without instantiating a listener? In my application, I have no need to be informed punctually for each change on phone state but only need to test if the phone is offline (due to radio signal not available) at a certain moment.

What I would is a (pseudo) `TelephonyManager.getServiceState()` to call once that unfortunately I cannot find.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123545/how-to-obtain-an-instance-of-servicestate it seems listener is only way

Comment: yes, unfortunatelly the only way: i've just verified it. Creating an instance of ServiceState through the default constructor, the getState() reports always the same (bad) result in each circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ServiceState` class, [documented here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html#ServiceState%28%29).

Call the `getState()` function which returns the current state of the phone.

Comment: @lorenzoff keep in mind that a listener will inform you when the state changes you can still choose not to take any actions on states that you are not interested in. You can use that in conjunction with your own code to control what actions you take and how often.

Comment: Thank you Orlymee, but it does not work. It seems that getState() always returns a STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE

Comment: Since you only want to find ourt about the networkstate why not use the NetworkInfo instead.

Comment: To clear up some confusion: `ServiceState` is simply a container object used by `onServiceStateChanged`, it doesn't contain any useful information unless passed in by the callback.